# itext 7 not importing outline / bookmarks

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am trying to merge PDF's together and keep the original bookmarks.  I am using the method described here:
[Merging documents with bookmarks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/clone-merging-documents-bookmarks#2399-insertandadaptoutlines.java)  however, not all of the bookmarks are imported.  That is, bookmarks from some files are imported but not from other files.

Using RUPS ([tool that can help you debug PDFs](https://github.com/itext/rups)) it looks like the issue is the object number of the outline object.  In the file that works, the outline tree is object 1 0 and in the file that does not work, the outline tree is object 16 0.  Or it may be related to the object order for the page tree in the file that imports, the outline tree comes before the page tree.  In the file that does not work, the page tree comes first.

Since RUPS can read and understand the outline tree, is there a setting that will allow itext 7 to import these bookmarks?

I am using itext community for c#.

Comment: What version of iText7 are you using? I remember fixing a bug that prevented the bookmarks from being copied using `PdfMerger`earlier this year.

Comment: Version 7.0.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping bookmarks while merging (and tag-structure) is possible by using the `PdfMerger` class:

```
public void createPdf(List<String> srcs, String dest) throws IOException, IOException {
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    pdfDoc.initializeOutlines();//Make sure the target document has outlines to merge into
    boolean mergeTags = true;
    boolean mergeOutlines = true; //Outlines are bookmarks, it is the named used for them in the spec.
    PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfDoc, mergeTags,mergeOutlines);//THis is also equal to new PdfMerger(pdfDoc)
    for (String src : srcs) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfDocument from = new PdfDocument(reader);
        merger.merge(from, 1, from.getNumberOfPages());
        from.close();
    }
    merger.close();
}
```

This works on 7.0.3 and onwards. For the C# version, the methods are the same, only with the names capitalized.

Comment: This made the difference for importing the bookmarks.  However, now, itext crashing for a PDF file that it did not have a problems with before.  I think it is having a problem with a stale bookmark (just guessing of course).

Comment: Here is the stack trace:
'at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.CloneOutlines(ICollection`1 outlinesToCopy, PdfOutline newParent, PdfOutline oldParent, IDictionary`2 page2page, PdfDocument toDocument)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.CopyOutlines(ICollection`1 outlines, PdfDocument toDocument, IDictionary`2 page2page)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.CopyPagesTo(IList`1 pagesToCopy, PdfDocument toDocument, Int32 insertBeforePage, IPdfPageExtraCopier copier)'

Comment: Looks like it, but without the input pdf I can't say for sure. You could probably find the root of the problem by debugging the process (find the AGPL source code on Github). RUPS is also a handy tool here. But that's in the scope for a different question already, and I don't have the time myself to go through with it.